# Doing a PUT to one URL/method from my JS client, another one getting hit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-api

I'm trying to build an API endpoint that takes multiple of a model I call `Element`s

The call goes to `Api::V1::ElementsController` to the `Foo` method.

```
scope module: :api, as: :api do
  namespace :v1 do
    resources :users, only: [:show, :update] do
        resources :elements
        put 'elements/element_update_multiple', to: 'elements#foo'
```

From `rake routes`

```
api_v1_user_elements_element_update_multiple PUT      /v1/users/:user_id/elements/element_update_multiple(.:format) api/v1/elements#foo
```

However, for some reason when I do a PUT to that route from my client, I get the following error in my terminal

> Started PUT "/v1/users/5/elements/element_update_multiple" for 10.0.2.2 at 2017-07-27 17:16:00 +0000
>   Cannot render console from 10.0.2.2! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
>     ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
>   Processing by Api::V1::ElementsController#update as JSON

It's falling into the `update` method rather than the `foo` method. Any idea why this is happening? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of the order of the routes in your routes file. You need to switch them around like this:

```
put 'elements/element_update_multiple', to: 'elements#foo'
resources :elements
```

`routes.rb` files are order-sensitive, so if Rails finds a matching route before it hits your custom PUT route (in this case it finds the update method in your resource routes) it will take that first, and never get to your custom PUT route.

Answer (score 0):

To add routes to a `resources` try [Adding Collection Routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-collection-routes) like so:

```
scope module: :api, as: :api do
  namespace :v1 do
    resources :users, only: [:show, :update] do
        resources :elements do
          collection do
            put 'element_update_multiple', to: 'elements#foo'
          end
        end
```